# How to use dirname when using include in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have common code in ruby that I extracted to a different file.

I have the following structure

```
+ root
|
+ someDirectory
|    |
|    + myFile.rb
|    + defaults.json  
|
+ common
     |
     + common.rb
```

`myFile.rb` has

```
 require '../common/common'
 include Common
```

and `common.rb` has

```
require `yaml`
defaults = YAML.load_file("#{File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))}/defaults.json")
```

The intention was that `default.json` would be read from the file doing the `include` command. but it is executing from the `common` directory.

How do I fix this?

## Edit

The including file is not the file I am executing.

Comment: AFAIK this can only be done by adding code to `myFile.rb`, because you only have access to the original path (`$0`) or the current file (`__FILE__`). You'd have to store the original filename in another variable then use that in the path given to `YAML.load_file`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$0` instead of `__FILE__`:

```
defaults = YAML.load_file("#{File.dirname(File.expand_path($0))}/defaults.json")
```

Observe:

```
llama@llama:~/Code/tmp$ cat somedir/myfile.rb
require_relative '../somedir2/myfile2'
llama@llama:~/Code/tmp$ cat somedir2/myfile2.rb 
puts File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))
puts File.dirname(File.expand_path($0))
llama@llama:~/Code/tmp$ ruby somedir/myfile.rb 
/home/llama/Code/tmp/somedir2
/home/llama/Code/tmp/somedir
```

`__FILE__` refers to the actual file being executed, while `$0` refers to where the file is being required from (they will be equal if you're executing the Ruby file directly).

Comment: the including file is not the one being executed.